# How RSA generate two primes number from passphrase

Tags: rsa

I know that two primes number p and q and e can conduct public and private key encrypt and decrypt functionality,but I don't understand how an passphrase enter by user can be convert to some 1024 or 2048 bit primes.

I only know using ASCII to convert to number but don't know how to convert to two primes for p and  q.

Comment: It's not hard. Most RSA key generation algorithms rely on a cryptographic random number generator (CSPRNG) for various things. Just modify the CSPRNG to use the password as it's sole source of entropy and you have a  deterministic process. Of course the RNG is not secure when you do it that way. Generating RSA keys this way is almost always the wrong solution to whatever requirements you have. The only scenario I can think of is a device with *no* non-volatile storage at all.

Comment: But look like passpharse will not affect the private key,so the passpharse is like hash into some static number?If it is random hash how they can decrypt it?

Comment: i have to disagree with @JamesKPolk here: if you need to derive a key from a passphrase please use something like PBKDF2 first, even if you plan on just putting entropy into a CSPRNG. This does not raise the security in terms of a stronger RSA key, but can help siginifcantly against exhaustive key searches